# Spring: Why have more than a single cache

Tags: java, spring, performance, caching, spring-boot

I'm going through Spring's Cache Abstraction features and [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-annotations-cacheable) line has caught my eye

> While in most cases, only one cache is declared, the annotation allows
>   multiple names to be specified so that more than one cache are being
>   used.

The above line is referring to this snippet that follows the above statements in their documentation.

```
@Cacheable({"books", "isbns"})
public Book findBook(ISBN isbn) {...}
```

Why would there be a need to have more than one cache for the same method? Wouldn't a single cache be sufficient for each behavior (function) that needs to be cached? What would be an appropriate use case for this be?

Answer (score 3):

The multiple cache names means that both/every cache is checked and if the required key is found in any of caches, the cached value is returned and the method body is not called.

One possible use case is when you have caches that are populated from different sources(e.g. database load and online/rest service calls) and you have to check both.

Indeed in most cases only one cache should be enough.